# Diversity within Blog Entries

Tags: ee3, entry

I was looking at this website:
https://mobirise.com/bootstrap-template/blog.html

It's a blog page that has interesting diversity on each blog entry. I'm wondering how I can build something similar in EE. Is it possible to create a field where the user can pick from posting a video, a gallery or slider on every blog entry? If so, how?

Comment: We can create fields for almost everything in EECMS. Just set them and the user can fill the wanted. I'm not following. I'm sorry.

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear. With EE, I find there is so much wonderful flexibility I'm shadie on following through a vision I have. Romans-8--31-39 answered my question quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the most basic, you could just create a different field for each one of those items and let the user pick 1 or more to add files or data to. Then on the template, lay out your page conditionally depending on what fields have data.

You can also spice up the fields by using some 3rd party options like [Channel Videos](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-videos) and [Ansel](https://buzzingpixel.com/software/ansel-ee) (for image edit/management). Another add-on that would give the user the ability to choose what fields to add per/entry is [Bloqs](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bloqs-blocks-for-ee3).

Comment: When you say "lay out your page conditionally" you mean using the dynamic parameter tags for our layout templates, right? I've heard of several conditional tags before. The ones I just mentioned along with option css conditional tags. I just want to be sure on which tags you mean.

Comment: I meant conditional statements in the template code. i.e.: {if field_one} show this block of html {if:elseif field_two} show a dif. block of html {if:else} default {/if} ( https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html )